# Can't set native monitor resolution in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, display, resolution

I have a SyncMaster 920nw display hooked up to an HP running Windows 7 with an on-board graphics card.

This has been working just fine until this morning, when I woke up the computer and the screen resolution was all wonky (aspect ration was way off).

I can go in to display settings and see that the monitor is IDed correctly. I even updated the drivers, but every time I pick a resolution option, it's clearly the wrong aspect ration and teh monitor, itself, puts up a message "not native resolution, 1440x900 recommended".

Alas, no where can I find this particular resolution option. It's not on the default resolution options nor in the advanced settings nor in the 'Intel Graphics Media Accelerator Driver' control panel.

Any ideas? Are there any recommended software tools for forcing a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

And...the solution ended up being easier than I would have thought. I left the monitor on, and rebooted the machine.

When Windows came back up, I could go in the display control panel and NOW, magically, the 1440x900 (recommended) option appeared.